# Cross Side Scripting

Tags: geojson

I am Hit particular URL in Browser .This URL appear Bug in webpage. 
I think ,it's Cross Side Scripting But I am not Sure. please suggest me how to resolve it?

{"roomCapacity":null,"roomIds":["1","2","3"],"roomStatus":null,"roomType":null,"rooms":["R1","R2","R3"]}

Answer (score 0):

That's probably some JavaScript that didn't register, and it's Cross SITE Scripting.